# requirejs loading file from different path

Tags: safari, requirejs, require

I've a webpage , where I've included the requirejs via script tag like -

```
<script data-main="/media/course-book-app/courses.require.main.js" src="/media/common/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

On Safari browser, I'm getting error like - 
[image]

What is causing this issue?
This issue is very frequent on Safari but on chrome it is less frequent.

[Testing URL](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/CK-12-Biology-FlexBook-2.0/section/1.1/primary/lesson/Scientific-Investigation-BIO)

Answer (score 0):

From https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror (which is linked right there in the error). Follow the instructions and look at the script that caused the error

> This occurs when the script.onerror function is triggered in a
>   browser. This usually means there is a JavaScript syntax error or
>   other execution problem running the script. To fix it, examine the
>   script that generated the error in a script debugger.
>
> This error may not show up in IE, just other browsers, and instead, in
>   IE you may see the No define call for ... error when you see "Script
>   error". This is due to IE's quirks in detecting script errors.

Comment: But, the actual error is that requirejs trying to load jquery with incorrect path. jquery path is set as https://www.ck12.org/media/common/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js in the requirejs configuration - https://st2.ck12.org/media/build-20180823150033/course-book-app/courses.require.main.js . There is no jquery present at root level which is resulting in 404.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to use requirejs correctly. This ensures the configuration gets loaded before loading any module -

```
define('requireconfig', function(){
    require.config({
        paths: {
          "jquery":    "/common/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min",
          "backbone":  "/common/vendor/backbone/backbone.min-1.1.2",
          "underscore":  mediaPath + "/common/vendor/underscore/underscore.min-1.7.0"
        },
        shim: {
           backbone : {
            deps: ["jquery","underscore"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        }
    });    
});

define('main', ['requireconfig'], function () {
    'use strict';
});

// loading main module which loads the requirejs configuration

requirejs(['main'],()=>{
   requirejs(['jquery'], ($)=>{//jquery loaded});
}, ()=>{//error loading module})
```